# generating random matrix

Tags: matrix, random-generation, independence

My problem is this:
I have a matrix with three columns. I created a second matrix with only two columns where column1 is the first column (col1) from the first matrix and column2 = 0.01*col1*col2*col3.
Now I need to generate a random matrix with same distribution. Both vectors seem to be quite normal but with different parameters.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which matrix do you need, the 1st or the 2nd? Are you just wondering how to generate normal random data?

Comment: What do you mean by "vectors seem to be quite normal but"? Normally distributed? What about the three column-vectors of the first matrix?

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to generate random matrices: One important reference with well defined algorithms by Ojala et. al. is available here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sam.10042/full